# HTML include page as pure text

Tags: php, html, get, ip

I am trying to get user ip by including a file in html,

```
     ob_start();
?>
   <object content="text" data="http://wtfismyip.com/text"> </object>
<?php
 $ip = ob_get_clean();
```

This code does work as I get the users ip, any idea how to get the output as pure text instead of as an object?
For exampe filtering the output variable?

NOTE: I can not use the $_SERVER due to proxying.

Comment: header("Content-Type: text/plain");

Comment: Was thinking of a method to strip the html actually, but that works very well. However, what if he wants the text embedded in more html?

Comment: I need the variable to be able to be set into database - pure text.
When I tried to add that header the HTML code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See this question

[Get IP address and browser code of visitors for any html page which supports image redirection like stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462250/get-ip-address-and-browser-code-of-visitors-for-any-html-page-which-supports-ima/22462559?noredirect=1#comment34166887_22462559)

easier way to get ip

It can be done only using 3rd party service.

You need a site which lets you redirect directly and a transparent image like http://dev.w3.org/2007/mobileok-ref/test/data/ROOT/GraphicsForSpacingTest/1/largeTransparent.gif

Step 1; Now go to site here, http://www.shorter.in/ 
Step 2; Shrink the transparent url http://dev.w3.org/2007/mobileok-ref/test/data/ROOT/GraphicsForSpacingTest/1/largeTransparent.gif

Here I have got  http://shorter.in/StackTrack
and 
Track URL  : http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack

Now just add `<img src="http://shorter.in/StackTrack"></img>` to you page 
and see visitors here; http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack

The visitors of this page can be seen here http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack because of image below

[a busy cat http://shorter.in/StackTrack](http://shorter.in/StackTrack)

You can also use tinyurl.com or any other web service which lets you redirect immediately.

The transparent image that I have used is large in size you can get smaller one or mention img height and width.

Hope this helps you.