# Get IP address and browser code of visitors for any html page which supports image redirection like stackoverflow

Tags: html, imageshack

I want to track visitors in my site which runs on normal html. Is there any way to track the user's/visitor's IP and Browser code using simple html code?

Note: I'm not using server side programming like php, jsp, node.js etc.
It is a normal html file without js.

Comment: No. You need server side code. You could use something like Google Analytics, however.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik I think it can be done :)

Comment: Check your server's access logs.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik sorry im not using js as I have mentioned

Comment: @j08691 I don't have access to it.

Comment: @JohnyPie JavaScript isn't serverside code. You can put JavaScript code in a straight HTML file.

Comment: Suppose it is possible to grab that info where are you planning to store it?

Comment: @CezaryWojcik But node.js is sever side scripting lang. Google it :)

Comment: @JohnyPie Not all JavaScript is node.js...

Comment: @CezaryWojcik i totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done only using 3rd party service.

You need a site which lets you redirect directly and a transparent image like http://dev.w3.org/2007/mobileok-ref/test/data/ROOT/GraphicsForSpacingTest/1/largeTransparent.gif

Step 1; Now go to site here, http://www.shorter.in/ 
Step 2; Shrink the transparent url http://dev.w3.org/2007/mobileok-ref/test/data/ROOT/GraphicsForSpacingTest/1/largeTransparent.gif

Here I have got  http://shorter.in/StackTrack
and 
Track URL  : http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack

Now just add `<img src="http://shorter.in/StackTrack"></img>` to you page 
and see visitors here; http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack

The visitors of this page can be seen here http://shorter.in/track.php?alias=StackTrack because of image below

[a busy cat http://shorter.in/StackTrack](http://shorter.in/StackTrack)

You can also use tinyurl.com or any other web service which lets you redirect immediately.

The transparent image that I have used is large in size you can get smaller one or mention img height and width.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This will require `PHP`, I think. Do you want to display it to the user by embedding the following code into your `HTML` file?:

```
<?php
    $user = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    echo "<p>You are viewing this page using:<br /><b>$user</b>.</p>\n";
    echo "<p>Your IP Address is:<br /><b>$ip</b>.</p>\n";
?>
```

Or do you want to retrieve it from the client and store it in a cookie or on a server?

Comment: Didn't the OP  rule out serverside stuff?

Comment: Just because the OP rules it out doesn't mean we can magically provide a working answer without server-side stuff. If it can't be done without server-side code then a correct answer will include server-side code, whether the OP likes it or not.